# string Replace not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, replace

```
string mystring="the are boys";

string[] tags = {"the"};

string[] replace ={"they"}

mystring.Replace(tags[0],replace[0]) // is not working

mystring.Replace("the","they") // is working
```

I thought both are same but first statement is not working. The second one is. 
Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: I was almost scared that `mystring.Replace("the","they") // is working ` - is true. Verified that indeed it is not... Unclear why OP made such comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume that you don't assign the return value of `String.Replace` to the variable. But since strings are immutable you have to do that:

```
mystring = mystring.Replace(tags[0],replace[0])
```

Comment: +1. There should be about 7! similar questions with different titles :) also some would be questionable like "replace not string working aps.net in"

Comment: +1. short and concise. `strings are immutable`